# Appengine task runs for 5 seconds before throwing DeadlineExceededError

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have recently converted an app from using backends to modules. I was using backends for long running requests, primarily get requests to external url's (using the requests library). Since changing my app such that everything runs on the single default module I am getting DeadlineExceededError's. i.e.

```
DeadlineExceededError('The API call urlfetch.Fetch() took too long to respond and was cancelled.
```

I have read in the [appengine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Instance_scaling_and_class) that there is a:

> 60-second deadline for HTTP requests, 10-minute deadline for tasks

The requests I am running are run as a task (using deferred.defer(...) ). However the task starts at, for example, 15:51:54.489 and finishes at 15:51:59.600  - a grand total of 5 seconds before throwing the error.

In app.yml automatic scaling enabled as follows:

```
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 1
  max_idle_instances: 1
  max_pending_latency: 1s
```

It is not clear to me why this deadline error is being thrown. Could you please let me know how I can avoid throwing this error?

Comment: Logs for such exceptions might not be very explicit, you may want to check out this thread with interpretations about them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918582/deferred-task-request-deadline-exceeded-but-work-never-started?noredirect=1#comment50132217_30918582

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the exception mentions, the error is from `urlfetch.Fetch`, which every outbound HTTP request is routed through on App Engine, even if you use `urllib`, `requests`, or other libraries. And the default `deadline` for `urlfetch` is `5` seconds. So the problem is that your HTTP requests to external URLs are timing out. It seems unrelated to your switch from backends to regular instances. Probably a coincidence.

[This page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors) has an overview of the various types of errors behind `DeadlineExceededError`.

Comment: Problem seems to have been solved by setting urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(600) in the requests init.py and in appengine_config.py.